# how to send invitation to another player using game center?

Tags: objective-c, game-center

I am new to game centre and I am building multiplayer game. I have different users in my tableview; now I want to send an invite for a match to a specific user. For sending the invitation I am using this code:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;

request.playersToInvite = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:player.playerId, nil];
request.inviteMessage = @"Your Custom Invitation Message Here";

request.inviteeResponseHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse response)
{
    [self updateUIForPlayer: playerID accepted: (response == GKInviteeResponseAccepted)];
};
```

But how to receive that invitation? I think I have to implement a method for this in GameKitHelper class but I am not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

my teacher helped me with this and i thought to post working code here if anyone stuck here can use this code.

```
- (void)inviteFriends: (NSArray*) friends
{
       GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2;
    request.recipients =  friends;
    request.inviteMessage = @"Your Custom Invitation Message Here";
    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch* match, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            //Invite has not been sent

            //  //NSLog(@"Invitation has not been sent");
        }
        else if (match != nil)
        {
            //whatever you want to do when the receiver accepts the invite
            //NSLog(@"Invitation has  been sent with match object = %@",match);

        }
    }];
    request.recipientResponseHandler= ^(GKPlayer *player, GKInviteeResponse response)
    {

        //NSLog(@"response Get From Other User.");

        switch (response) {
            case GKInviteeResponseAccepted:
            {

            }
                break;
            case GKInviteeResponseDeclined:
            {

            }
                break;
            case GKInviteeResponseFailed:
            {

            }
                break;
            case GKInviteeResponseIncompatible:
            {

            }
                break;
            case GKInviteeResponseUnableToConnect:
            {


            }
                break;
            case GKInviteeResponseNoAnswer:
            {


            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    };


}
```